# How to read GridControl cell value by its row and column index

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I am working with GridControl of DevExpress to show the data in different kinds of views. Previously when I was using DataGridView I can access the cell value by

```
DataGridViewObject.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex/ColumnName].Value
```

Now I want to access the same cell value in GridControl with GridView object similarly but don't want to access such line in for loop of Rows and also not on cell click event where I get RowIndex and ColumnIndex because I need to maintain both these in global area of my application, so that I can use this syntax to directly fetch the particular cell value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GridView's [GetRowCellValue method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRowCellValue.overloads) which will take a row index and field name or GridColumn instance to return a value.

For instance:

```
var cellValue = myGridView.GetRowCellValue(5, "EmployeeName");
```

See also:

[Read and Modify Cell Values in Code](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Cell-Values-Editors-and-Validation#code)

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like follow:

```
private void BindData()
        {
            bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = _Supplier.Select();
            gcSupplier.DataSource = bs;
            txtCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colCode.FieldName);
            txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colName.FieldName);
            txtAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colAddress.FieldName);
            txtNationalCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colNationalCode.FieldName);
            txtEconomicCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colEconomicCode.FieldName);
            txtPostalCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colPostalCode.FieldName);
            txtTelNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colTelNumber.FieldName);
            txtFaxNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colFaxNumber.FieldName);
            txtMobileNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colMobileNumber.FieldName);
            txtEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, colEmail.FieldName);
            luePersonType.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bs, colPersonType_Id.FieldName);
            lueState.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bs, colState_Id.FieldName);
            lueCity.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bs, colCity_Id.FieldName);
        }
```